# Change write access permission of dataset in sas

Tags: unix, sas

I have few data sets whose write access needs to be transferred to another user.I am aware about chmod command, but if i am using that then i am giving write permission to all other users. I just want file owner write access be transferred or be given to another single user.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of CHMOD, use CHOWN:

chown command changes the user and/or group ownership of for given file. The syntax is:

```
chown owner-user file
chown owner-user:owner-group file
chown owner-user:owner-group directory
chown options owner-user:owner-group file
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/

Comment: Not working.. getting error as chown: filename: Not owner

Comment: Only root/superusers can run `chown`, I believe, and only the same people or the file owner can run `chmod`. Try `sudo chown...`

Comment: @shael Can you delete the file? Do you have rights to do that? If yes, then you can copy the file into a brand new file that will belong to you, delete old file and replace it with your own. Now you have owner rights to change owner. Otherwise speak to your admin to either become an admin or supersuer with permissions to change owner.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod` allows you to grant file permissions to specific users via the use of Access Control Lists (ACLs). Without knowing more about your system it's difficult to advise on how to create one of these - e.g. Solaris is quite different from Linux in this regard.