# Setting Permission For SAS dataset

Tags: permissions, sas, dataset

I'm new to SAS. I'm wondering if there is a way to ensure all the dataset my SAS program creates have read/write permissions for everyone. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What OS are you using? This is more of a question about system administration than it is about SAS.

Comment: oh, I see. SAS outputs the dataset in a UNIX environment.

Comment: If Unix/Linux, and you want all files read/writeable by everyone, I would think setting your umask might be enough.

Comment: Are you using Base SAS?  Or are you in a server/client environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Base SAS command that expressly sets the file permissions. However, if your SAS administrator has allowed UNIX commands to be sent to the server, there is a solution.

SAS has published a sample macro demonstrating the sending of custom operating system commands to set file permission:

[Sample 25198: Macro to change the Unix permissions of a SAS® data set](https://support.sas.com/kb/25/198.html)

Paraphrasing from the link, you'd do something like this:

```
filename whatever pipe "chmod 777 /my/data/set/test.sas7bdat";

data _null_;
    file whatever;
 run;
```

There is also the SAS `X` command. Such as:

`X "chmod 777 /my/data/set/test.sas7bdat;"`
, but again, probably forbidden.

Here are overviews of chmod:

[Change write access permission of dataset in sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732533/change-write-access-permission-of-dataset-in-sas)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

As an alternative, you might be able to log onto the SAS file server using an SSH client like putty, and issue the `chmod` command on the data set.

Comment: The XCMD system option controls whether you can execute OS commands. It is off by default in BI server environments, but if it is off in your environment, I would encourage you to lobby your admin to turn it back on.  It's handy.  For arguments in favor of XCMD, see http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/08/31/the-case-for-xcmd-privileges-in-sas-enterprise-guide/.